# Putting Canvas and Context in another Object?

Tags: coffeescript, html5-canvas

The *following* is part of my configuration file (**config.coffee**):

```
define [], () ->
  config =
    world:
      canvas: {}
      context: {}
      init: (canvasName) ->
        config.world.canvas = document.getElementById canvasName
        config.world.context = config.world.canvas.getContext '2d'
    character:
      canvas: {}
      context: {}
      init: (canvasName) ->
        config.character.canvas = document.getElementById canvasName
        config.character.context = config.character.canvas.getContext '2d'
```

As you can see, I've put the **canvas** object and the **context** object in another object, called **config**!

Could this *work*? Because I get **no Browser feedback**.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this all of your code? There wouldn't be any browser feedback as you aren't calling any of your functions. 
There is no problem with nesting your functions inside the object, so this should work.

Comment: this is just an excerpt of my code. (the part that matters)